# UITableView Cell Background Images initial scroll lag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an app where there is a table view pulling cell background images strictly from assets.  I have noticed that the fps drops on the initial scroll due to loading these images into the table view. (if I just replace the UIImage with a black box or give all the same image the scroll is seamless).  Once all of the images in the table view have loaded for the first time, the scroll action has no lag.

Currently each image can vary between 1.8MB and 3MB.  The aspect ratios are around 1125x295 for 3x images and scaled down for 1x and 2x devices. There is an initial.scaleAspectFill being called when the background images are set as well, but I don't know if that would be the problem.  I have found this problem exists with a 6s, X, ipad mini and pro.

1. What are the max file size you would suggest for background images?
2. If I try to pull the UIImages on a background thread, it is not allowed because it UIImages need to process on the main thread (xCode error).
3. Should I try to figure out how to precache these images?

This is the method that sets background images

```
fileprivate let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView(axId: "backgroundImage")
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}()
```

In the init menu for the cell the backgroundImageView gets added to the contentView as a subView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do #2 pull images from the background. Load the images to memory from the backgroundThread then assign it thru the mainThread

```
    fileprivate let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let image = getFromSource()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                view.image = image
                view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                view.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
        }

        return view
    }()
```

Or you could cache the images using [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher), which comes with its own way of caching the images. Pretty neat.

Also you might want to implement prepareForReuse, to unload the previous images when the cells are going to be reused.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

   //Do your clean up here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried to Dispatch the image retrieval and there is still the initial lag.

Is KingFisher geared more towards retrieving images from the web?

And unfortunately I don't reuse cells or images in this specific view

Comment: Most-likely, but on my view since it will accept URL as parameter and you are loading from local storage. You could use KingFisher's Memory caching.

By the way, with the images at 1.8MB I think you could still optimize it for better loading.

Comment: Very helpful, I was wondering what a good size for an image <1.5 MB?

Comment: If these are static images/assets (e.g. buttons, icons) 100KB is already too much.. Try reducing to 500KB first and check the look and feel. By the way if you support iPhones 5, 5s, SE, I think they will also experience slow down if your images are too big.